# what is bes approach to put the javascript in a partials of sinatra view

Tags: javascript, sinatra, coffeescript, slim

I am developing a page for editing the profile of user. so i split it based on model. so the profile page view is going to have the following partials
 - navigation
 - user-login
 - user-personal 
 - user-photo

each one is going to have it own javascript/validation. I want to keep the js in the partials. I am using slim for view and coffee for javascript in the slim. this makes the javascript to be inline with the html.**Is it a good approach**(I want to keep the script together with the partial view of the model as it is more maintainable). I would like know your ideas on this approach. And inlining the js in dom leads to different problem
[why-is-jquery-wrap-executing-an-inline-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104617/why-is-jquery-wrap-executing-an-inline-javascript)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use coffeescript in slim templates you can do so but you will have to tell slim about that. Use a filter like this

```
:coffee
  your stuff inlined...
```

Or you call the cs via it's route and have coffeescript parse it. Then you can also put it into your routes.

Comment: I don't want to inline it(right now I have it that way)..but it make more sense in term of the validation code in javascript going with the model's view..which in partials..so is there a way leave it in the partials and still using some precompiler to pull it out and throw it as a separate js file