# why is jquery wrap executing an inline javascript

Tags: jquery

I tried to wrap an element with inline javascript and it is getting execute again...here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uk67F/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because when JQuery wraps a DOM element, it removes it, and re-inserts it into the DOM as a child element of the new wrapper element. If it contains inline JS, it'll get re-executed. That's just how it works. That's why you should keep your JS out of the DOM :)

A simple hack work-around if you MUST have your JS in that script block is to create a flag listener/setter, like so:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     if(window.helloworld !== true){
         alert('helloworld');
         window.helloworld = true;
     }
 </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/uk67F/2/

Of course I wouldn't recommend creating window properties like that in your production application, but the proof of concept is there, do with it what you will.

Comment: what is the solution to just wrap it

Comment: I think I am going to ahead with direct dom manipulation and have $.fn.wrap for it... http://jsfiddle.net/uk67F/3/